# Event listener three levels (from parent to grandchild)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dom-events

I am experiencing some issues when attaching event listener to a grandchild.

Both parent click and child click works as expected, only grandchildren clicks won't fire.

**Here is my current code:**

```
/* Parent */
$('body').on('click', 'div.left-menu-item', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('parent'); // <-- this works
});

/* Child */
$('body').on('click', 'div.left-menu-item div.dropdown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    console.log('child'); // <-- this works
});

/* Grandchild */
$('body').on('click', 'div.left-menu-item div.dropdown-menu.show a.edit', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    console.log('grandchild'); // <-- this does NOT work
});
```

Markup for the button were the issue is:

```
<a class="btn edit" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-pen"></i> <span>Edit</span>
</a>
```

I've also tried setting the grandchild eventlistener to:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.edit', function(e){
    console.log('grandchild'); <-- this doesnt work either
});
```

**New update.**

I added a click listener with wildcard so I can listen to all clicks:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

A total of 20 clicks are triggered, but when I click on .edit no clicks are detected still.

If I trigger click manually `$('.edit').trigger('click');` it works..

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML as well and create a snippet?

Comment: The problem is presumably that the selector is incorrect, but we can't help you without seeing the DOM structure. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Added relevant markup if you take into consideration the last eventlistener I added that I've also tried.

Comment: Your code is working just fine. For your cross reference, you can create a snippet as @T.J.Crowder said and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Inside `$(document).ready` I created an actual object named document (stupid, right?) which made everything crazy.

So I just renamed `var document = ....;` to `var documentObj = ....;` and everything worked as expected.

I am still somewhat confused about why some of the eventlisteners worked. I understand that overriding document is something that shouldn't happen and maybe overriding document caused `$('body').on('...', '...` to not work as expected since body is a child of document? But that doesn't explain why so many eventlisteners worked and only one did not trigger a click event.

Answer (score -1):

You could also tale advantage of event bubbling by attaching the listener only to the parent, and checking who emitted the event (through classes or node name/type).

```
$('div.left-menu-item').on('click', function(e){

  if( $(e.target).hasClass('dropdown') ) {
    // child logic
  } else if ( $(e.target).hasClass('edit') ) {
    // grandchild logic
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP is doing that. They're hooking the event on `body`.